# невозможно создать экземпляр абстрактного класса

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

Задача: 
Создать абстрактный базовый класс Pair с виртуальными арифметическими операциями. Реализовать
производные классы Complex и Rational

Моё примерное решение:

```
#pragma once
class Rational;
class Complex;
class Pair
{
public:
    virtual Rational& operator +=(const Rational& pr) = 0;
    virtual Rational& operator -=(const Rational& pr) = 0;
    virtual Rational& operator *=(const Rational& pr) = 0;
    virtual Rational& operator /=(const Rational& pr) = 0;

    virtual Complex& operator +=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
    virtual Complex& operator -=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
    virtual Complex& operator *=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
    virtual Complex& operator /=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
};
```

Rational.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include "Pair.h"

class Rational : public Pair
{
private:
    int numerator;
    unsigned int denominator;
    unsigned int gcd(int n1, int n2);
public:
    Rational()noexcept;
    Rational(const int &numerator, const unsigned int &denominator);
    Rational& operator +=(const Rational& rt)override;
    Rational& operator -=(const Rational& rt)override;
    Rational& operator *=(const Rational& rt)override;
    Rational& operator /=(const Rational& rt)override;
    friend Rational& operator + (const Rational& rt, const Rational& rt2);
    friend Rational& operator - (const Rational& rt, const Rational& rt2);
    friend Rational& operator * (const Rational& rt, const Rational& rt2);
    friend Rational& operator / (const Rational& rt, const Rational& rt2);
};

#include <iostream>
#include "Pair.h"
#include "Rational.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rational rat;
             ^^^
    Rational f(15, 5);
             ^
    Rational s(16, 8);
             ^
}
```

Не абстрактный `Rational` вдруг стал абстрактным?

Comment: Класс `Rational` и не переставал быть абстрактным. Вы реализовали только 4 метода из 8 абстрактных.

Comment: @kodv А то что я так декларирую виртуальные методы, это нормально?

Comment: А если у вас будет еще сотня типов, Вы добавите еще `сотня * кол-во_операторов_типа` объявлений в абстракцию?

Comment: @Bogdan Я сомневаюсь что я делаю правильно. Я написал сюда в надежде что мне покажут как делать это правильно.

Comment: @ANurbaev, не стоит декларировать методы конкретных классов в абстрактном. Класс `Pair` не должен ничего знать о том, какие у него потомки. В Вашем случае получается явное нарушение [принципа инверсии зависимости (SOLID)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9). У Вас абстракция зависит от деталей, а этого не должно быть. Правильнее было бы передавать и возвращать ссылки на `Pair`.

Comment: Задачка-то с подвохом, имхо. Обычно абстрактные классы делают, когда объекты принадлежат к какой-то общей категории, и часть операций для них тоже общая, чтобы кидать разные экземпляры в одну коллекцию и использовать общий функционал не зная о деталях реализации. Здесь же похоже на то, что придется решать через двойную диспетчеризацию и паттерн Посетитель возможно, потому что в операторе второй операнд тоже абстрактный.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно подразумевается такое решение.

```cpp
template <class T>
class Pair
{
public:
    virtual Pair& operator +=(const T& pr) = 0;
    virtual Pair& operator -=(const T& pr) = 0;
    virtual Pair& operator *=(const T& pr) = 0;
    virtual Pair& operator /=(const T& pr) = 0;
};

class Rational : public Pair<Rational>
{
private:
    int numerator;
    unsigned int denominator;
    unsigned int gcd(int n1, int n2);
public:
    Rational()noexcept;
    Rational(const int &numerator, const unsigned int &denominator);
    Rational& operator +=(const Rational& rt) override;
    Rational& operator -=(const Rational& rt) override;
    Rational& operator *=(const Rational& rt) override;
    Rational& operator /=(const Rational& rt) override;
};
```

Comment: @ANurbaev, компилятор это переживет :)

Answer (score 1):

Например, для класса `Rational` вы не определили функции

```
virtual Complex& operator +=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
virtual Complex& operator -=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
virtual Complex& operator *=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
virtual Complex& operator /=(const Complex& pr) = 0;
```

Поэтому класс `Rational` по-прежнему остается абстрактным.

Аналогичная проблема имеет место для класса `Complex`, в котором не определены операторы для объектов класса `Rational`.

Абстрактный класс `Pair` не должен содержать ссылки на классы `Rational` и `Complex`. Вы должны в классе `Pair` объявить операторы для объектов ссылочных типов `Pair`. Также, как следует из названия самого класса, класс `Pair` должен содержать по крайней мере два члена данных, которые будут использоваться в классах `Rational` и `Complex`.

Классы могут выглядеть примерно следующим образом. как показано в демонстрационной программе ниже.

```
#include <iostream>

class Pair
{
public:
    Pair( int first, int second ) : first( first ), second( second )
    {
    }

    Pair() : Pair( 0, 0 )
    {
    }

    virtual Pair & operator +=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
/*
    virtual Pair & operator -=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
    virtual Pair & operator *=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
    virtual Pair & operator /=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
*/
protected:
    int first, second;
};

class Complex : public Pair
{
public:
    Complex( int real, int image ) : Pair( real, image )
    {
    }

    Complex() : Complex( 0, 0 )
    {
    }

    Complex & operator +=( const Pair &p ) override
    {
        const Complex &c = reinterpret_cast<const Complex &>( p );

        this->first += c.real();
        this->second += c.image();

        return *this;
    }
/*
    Complex & operator -=( const Pair & ) override; 
    Complex & operator *=( const Pair & ) override; 
    Complex & operator /=( const Pair & ) override; 
*/
    int real() const { return this->first; }
    int image() const { return this->second; }
};

int main() 
{
    Complex c( 10, 10 );

    c += Complex( 5, 5 );

    std::cout << "{ " << c.real() << ", " << c.image() << " }\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
{ 15, 15 }
```

Если хотите объявить класс `Pair`, как класс, зависящий от шаблонного параметра, то определение класса `Pair` может выглядеть так, как показано в следующей демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Pair
{
public:
    Pair( const T &first, const T &second ) : first( first ), second( second )
    {
    }

    Pair() : Pair( T(), T() )
    {
    }

    virtual Pair & operator +=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
/*
    virtual Pair & operator -=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
    virtual Pair & operator *=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
    virtual Pair & operator /=( const Pair & ) = 0; 
*/
protected:
    T first, second;
};

template <class T>
class Complex : public Pair<T>
{
public:
    Complex( const T &real, const T &image ) : Pair<T>( real, image )
    {
    }

    Complex() : Complex( T(), T() )
    {
    }

    Complex & operator +=( const Pair<T> &p ) override
    {
        const Complex &c = reinterpret_cast<const Complex &>( p );

        this->first += c.real();
        this->second += c.image();

        return *this;
    }
/*
    Complex & operator -=( const Pair<T> & ) override; 
    Complex & operator *=( const Pair<T> & ) override; 
    Complex & operator /=( const Pair<T> & ) override; 
*/
    const T & real() const { return this->first; }
    const T & image() const { return this->second; }
};

int main() 
{
    Complex<int> c( 10, 10 );

    c += Complex<int>( 5, 5 );

    std::cout << "{ " << c.real() << ", " << c.image() << " }\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я тоже сколняюсь к тому, что `Pair` назван так не зря, потому, что и комплексные и рациональные числа имеют 2 по компонента. Только компонентами комплексного числа являются числа действительные, а не целые. Так что в любом случае речь наверняка о шаблонном базовом классе.

Comment: @extrn Это не принципиально, объявить шаблонный или нет базовый класс, так как в исходном вопросе шаблоны отсутствуют. Если есть желание, то можно класс Pair сделать шаблонным.

Comment: Да, но `Pair` у вас имеет конструктор, принимающий аргументы типа int, а также соответсвующие поля. Для `Complex` все это не нужно.

Comment: @extrn Я же написал, что если есть желание, то можно определить класс Pair как шаблонный класс.

Answer (score 0):

В С++ если, ты не переопределяешь чисто виртуальные методы в производном классе, то он считается тоже абстрактным